# Get MFA informations in C# program

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to get informations about MFA in my C# application. I already achieved to get satisfying results in Powershell but i'm struggling to make the same thing in C#.

My code in Powershell :

```
Get-MsolUser -SearchString c.test@mytenant.com | 
Where-Object {$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements -like “*”} | 
Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, @{n='MFA';e= 
{$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State}}, @{n='Methods'; e= 
{($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods).MethodType}}, @{n='Default Method'; e= 
{($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods).IsDefault}}

UserPrincipalName : c.test@mytenant.com
DisplayName       : Cyril test
MFA               : Enforced
Methods           : {OneWaySMS, TwoWayVoiceMobile, PhoneAppOTP, 
PhoneAppNotification}
Default Method    : {False, False, False, True}
```

As you can see, i get the MFA status and methods used.

Now, i want to do the same in C#.

My function :

```
public static List<string> GetMFA(Runspace runspace, string nom)
    {
        List<string> listResult = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            Command getLicenseCommand = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
            getLicenseCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("SearchString", nom));
            var pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipe.Commands.Add(getLicenseCommand);
            var props = new string[] { "displayname", "userprincipalname", "StrongAuthenticationRequirements" };
            Command CommandSelect = new Command("Select-Object");
            CommandSelect.Parameters.Add("Property", props);
            pipe.Commands.Add(CommandSelect);

            // Execute command and generate results and errors (if any).
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipe.Invoke();
            if (results.Count != 0)
            {
                var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                if (error.Count > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception(error[0].ToString());
                }

                foreach (PSObject resultat in results)
                {

                    string dn = resultat.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
                    string upn = resultat.Properties["userprincipalname"].Value.ToString();
                    string mfa = resultat.Properties["StrongAuthenticationRequirements"].Value.ToString();

                    string res = dn + '/' + upn + '/' + mfa;
                    listResult.Add(res);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        return listResult;
    }
```

The "StrongAuthenticationRequirements" property isn't returning something like "Enforced" but

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement]
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Did you bother to explore the list and its objects?

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the answer. I didn't managed to loop through what it seems to be a List. Even Visual Studio tools in debug mode can't go further than this. Anyway i managed to get some results by querying direcly the powershell command and i got all the information in the raw result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the OP doesn't care any more, but for the next person who struggled with this like I have for the last few hours, I'm posting an answer.

In order to call these items, you must include the Microsoft.Online.Administration references which are included as DLLs within the MSOL PowerShell module package.

In Visual Studio:

1. Right Click References
2. Select "Add Reference"
3. Open the "Browse.."
4. Navigate to the installation location of the MSOL module. This may vary depending on if it was installed on the user/machine scope.
5. I added Microsoft.Online.Administration.PSModule

You will now be able to parse the results in c#.

Note: It was my experience that I needed to explicitly cast the items into a variable before I could use them.

---

Edit:

I removed the unnecessary reference to the resources.dll after further testing.